# What does the text on this building say?

Tags: latin, translation

A friend of mine spotted this while waking around Amsterdam. I don't recognize the script and can't make sense of it so I thought I'd ask for your help.

[image]

What's that text between XXXVII and ANNO? What script is it in? What year is this timestamp referring to?

Comment: See the *Apostrophus* and *Vinculum* paragraphs at the end of the Wikipedia article on [Roman numerals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals#Large_numbers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the Westertoren Tower in Amsterdam, the Nederlands. The numbers are regular Roman numerals, but written in a fancy way. The first one is what looks like `c|ɔ`, but that is how `M`, 1000, is written, `m` with a tall middle mast. The second one is `|ɔ`, but that is actually `D`, 500, again, with a tall mast. Then go the usual Roman `C`, 100, and `XXXVII`, 37, which should all be summed up, making 1000 + 500 + 100 + 37 = [1637, and that is the year](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Westertoren_(Amsterdam)#Romeinse_cijfers) written on the Westertoren Tower.